# Bash search and run previous command

Tags: bash, command-history

According to *O'Reily's Bash Pocket Reference (page 40)* the following will run the most recent command that contains `string`:

```
!?string[?]
```

I'm running said command but I always get back:

```
bash: !?string[?: event not found
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Bash manual:

```
!?string[?]
     Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position
     in the history list containing string.  The trailing ? may be
     omitted if string is followed immediately by a newline.
```

The `[?]` means that the trailing `?` is optional. You will find this convention used in most synopsis sections in the on-line manuals, for example

```
NAME
     ls – list directory contents

SYNOPSIS
     ls [-1AaCcdFfgHhikLlmnopqRrSsTtux] [file ...]
```